# Mapping a texture to an imported object Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, mapping

I'm having trouble mapping a texture to an object imported into Opengl. I found a tutorial to import an obj file, but I can't figure out mapping a texture.

This is the code I have written:

```
    class Model
    {
    public:
        Model();
        Model(string modelFilename, string textureFilename);

        void LoadTexture(string fileName);
        void LoadObj(const string& filename, vector<glm::vec4> &vertices, vector<glm::vec3> &normals, vector<GLushort> &elements);
        void Draw();
    private:
        vector<glm::vec4> m_Vertices;
        vector<glm::vec3> m_Normals;
        vector<GLushort> m_Elements;

        string m_ModelFilename;
        int m_Texture;
        string m_TextureName;
    };

Model::Model(string modelFilename, string textureFilename)
{
    m_ModelFilename = modelFilename;
    m_TextureName = textureFilename;

    LoadObj(m_ModelFilename, m_Vertices, m_Normals, m_Elements);
    LoadTexture(m_TextureName);
}

void Model::LoadTexture(string TextureName)         
{
   // Local storage for bmp image data.
   BitMapFile *image[1];

        string filename = TextureName;
        filename.append(".bmp");

       // Load the texture.
       image[0] = getBMPData(filename);

       // Bind grass image to texture index[i]. 
       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture); 
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
       glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, image[0]->sizeX, image[0]->sizeY, 0, 
                    GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image[0]->data);
}

void Model::LoadObj(const string& filename, vector<glm::vec4> &vertices, vector<glm::vec3> &normals, vector<GLushort> &elements) {
  ifstream in(filename, ios::in);
  if (!in) { cerr << "Cannot open " << filename << endl; exit(1); }

  string line;
  while (getline(in, line)) {
    if (line.substr(0,2) == "v ") {
      istringstream s(line.substr(2));
      glm::vec4 v; s >> v.x; s >> v.y; s >> v.z; v.w = 1.0f;
      vertices.push_back(v);
    }  else if (line.substr(0,2) == "f ") {
      istringstream s(line.substr(2));
      GLushort a,b,c;
      s >> a; s >> b; s >> c;
      a--; b--; c--;
      elements.push_back(a); elements.push_back(b); elements.push_back(c);
    }
    else if (line[0] == '#') { /* ignoring this line */}
   // else { /* ignoring this line */ }
  }

  normals.resize(vertices.size(), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
  for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i+=3) {
    GLushort ia = elements[i];
    GLushort ib = elements[i+1];
    GLushort ic = elements[i+2];
    glm::vec3 normal = glm::normalize(glm::cross(glm::vec3(vertices[ib]) - glm::vec3(vertices[ia]), glm::vec3(vertices[ic]) - glm::vec3(vertices[ia])));
    normals[ia] = normals[ib] = normals[ic] = normal;
  }
}

void Model::Draw()
{
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture);

        for (int i = 0; i < m_Elements.size(); i+=3) 
        {
            GLushort ia = m_Elements[i];
            GLushort ib = m_Elements[i+1];
            GLushort ic = m_Elements[i+2];

            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
                glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
                glNormal3f(m_Normals[ia].x,m_Normals[ia].y,m_Normals[ia].z);//
                glNormal3f(m_Normals[ib].x,m_Normals[ib].y,m_Normals[ib].z);//
                glNormal3f(m_Normals[ic].x,m_Normals[ic].y,m_Normals[ic].z);//
                glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);glVertex3f(m_Vertices[ia].x,m_Vertices[ia].y,m_Vertices[ia].z);
                glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);glVertex3f(m_Vertices[ib].x,m_Vertices[ib].y,m_Vertices[ib].z);
                glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);glVertex3f(m_Vertices[ic].x,m_Vertices[ic].y,m_Vertices[ic].z);
            glEnd();
            glEnd();
        }
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

Model model;

void setup(void) 
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); 

    model = Model("monkey.obj", "launch");

   // Specify how texture values combine with current surface color values.
   glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE); 

   glEnable(GL_BLEND); // Enable blending.

   // Cull back faces.
   glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
   glCullFace(GL_BACK);

   // stops GL_QUAD from showing faces by priority
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

}

// Drawing routine.
void drawScene(void)
{
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   glLoadIdentity();

   model.Draw();

   glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

When i run the program this is what happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW7B3.jpg
It seems to be mapping the entire image to each triangle, but I don't know how to fix it. Anyone have any ideas? Thank you in advance

Comment: OBJ files can contain texture coordinates (`vt` records). Find/generate files with texture coordinates, and then read them in your parsing code.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Oh really? How would I set that up though?

Comment: @WhyYouNoWork: Well, by reading the texture coordinated from the OBJ file and using those instead of the hardcoded values passed to glTexCoord. It's really frustrating commenting questions like "How would I set that up though?" if the code in the question proper already has almost everything in place. Why? Because it shows, that the asker didn't really do his research first, which in turn means, that it makes explaining things so much harder.

Comment: @datenwolf I understand the theory. I know what it is. The problem is I don't understand the execution. That is why I'm asking. I don't understand how to set it up in my code.

Comment: @WhyYouNoWork: Okay, I'll give you a few hints: You need an additional `vector<glm::vec2> m_TexCoords` similar to the `m_Normals` and `m_Vertices` class member variables. BTW, you should not call it *m_Vertices*, but rather `m_Positions` because a vertex is in fact the whole tuple of position + normal + texcoord + whatever else is required. In `Model::LoadObj` you have to add code to read in vertex texture coordinates just like you read the vertex positions (note that calculating the normals in your code is a bad idea, because it limits the 3D artists freedom to tweak illumination).

Comment: @WhyYouNoWork: Finally you pass the texture coordinates into OpenGL drawing just like you do it with texture coordinates. Also since you've already got all your data in `vector<glm::vec_>`, it's straightforward to replace the old and busted immediate mode (glBegin … glVertex … glEnd) with vertex arrays (I'd be tempted to call them new hotness, but vertex arrays have been around for well over 17 years and immediate mode shouldn't have been taught ever since.

Comment: @datenwolf Okay. Thank you for the advice. If I understand correctly then I have made the following changes: I added m_TexCoord to my class and The LoadOBJ function also takes in m_TexCoord. Within my function I have added a check to find "vt ". It's identical to my "v " condition except for this:(glm::vec2 v; s >> v.x; s >> v.y;) and pushing it to m_TexCoord. I'm still a bit lost on calling the texcoord properly though. As for normals I haven't actually put any lights in yet. I wanted to get my models working before that. If you think it should be removed from my load I can do that.

Comment: @datenwolf I have never heard of vertex arrays. I will have to look that up. If it can crunch all of that code that would be amazing.

Comment: @WhyYouNoWork Oh, one more thing, I just noticed. glNormal, glTexCoord and such just copy their parameters into a hidden global variable and only the call to glVertex will collect the values from all the vertex attribute variables. So if you have a number of glNormal or glTexCoord calls in tight succession only the values of the last of them will be considered by the following glVertex calls. The proper ordering is `glNormal, glTexCoord, glColor, glVertex, glNormal, glTexCoord, glColor, glVertex` and so on. However the ordering of things between glVertex calls doesn't matter, though.

Comment: @datenwolf Thank you for the info. I didn't know that. I have my stuff mostly rewritten now. I'm stuck on how to call the m_TexCoord in my draw function though. I thought it would be just filling in the values (glTexCoord2f(m_TexCoord[ia].x,m_TexCoord[ia].y)), but it gave me an assertion error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @WhyYouNoWork: Most likely the length of the vertex texture coordinate vector doesn't match the length of the other two attributes and you're running into an out-of-bounds access. Oh, one more thing: Your code is nesting two glBegin/glEnd blocks which is invalid. Also it's inefficient to start a new glBegin/glEnd block for each individual triangle; you can move glBegin before and glEnd after the `for` loop; still immediate mode is rather inefficient.

Comment: @datenwolf I looked at the file. For some reason Blender won't export the vt's in the .obj file. I seem to be running into another assertion error. my m_normals and m_verticies vectors aren't the same size after the function ends. Any idea why that would be? My code for finding vn is about the same as finding v except I added a second istringstream for the initial offset(istringstream init(line.substr(3)); init >> v.x; s >> v.y; s >> v.z;).

Comment: @datenwolf  Thank you for letting me know. I finally found a tutorial on vertex arrays. I will implement it soon, but first I want to get the texturing to work.